# CSS flex get the same behaivor as table

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to get the same behavior as a table. For example:

```
<div>
    <div class="flex row">
        <p>Short text</p>
        <p>Text </p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex row">
        <p>Very long text</p>
        <p>Text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the rows to be on the same vertical line as a table?

So basically I'm trying to achieve the following result with flexbox

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Short text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Very long text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't. Flexbox doesn't work like that. Use CSS tables instead.

Comment: This is a fact?

Comment: Yes...it is.If you want table behaviour, use CSS Table layout.

Comment: Check out CSS grid layouts: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/developer/css-grid/.

Comment: To do this with flexbox you would need to work with flex columns, not rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using flexbox given your HTML structure.

If you want table behaviour, using divs, use [**CSS Tables**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

A comparison for you.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.table {
  display: inline-table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Short text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Very long text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Short text</p>
    <p>Text </p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <p>Very long text</p>
    <p>Text </p>
  </div>

  <div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Only the markup?

Comment: Essentially yes.

Comment: So I can't use flexbox to get the same effect?

Comment: No. Flexbox can't equalise widths between rows unless you set a width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.row p { width: 100% }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="flex row">
    <p>Short text</p>
    <p>Text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex row">
    <p>Very long text</p>
    <p>Text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not the same result as a table. The lines are not straight.

Comment: You need to define the width in your solution. In the table solution, it just works.

Comment: There's no width in your table example.

Comment: I mean that in your solution you're defined a width.