# Resize thead height with respect to tbody height using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following table where the height of the `tbody` is dynamic. How can I make the height of the `thead` change dynamically in proportional to `tbody`, so that every cell of the `tbody` is perfectly aligned with the respective `thead`?

**P.S.** The table is obtained as an object, so its orientation cannot be edited as a `vertical table`.

```css
<style>
  h1
{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
    #tabulu thead
    {
        float:left
    }
    #tabulu tbody
    {
        float:right
    }
    #tabulu tbody td
    {
        display: block;
        padding:8px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        /*multiline wrap*/
        white-space:pre-wrap; 
    }
    #tabulu thead th {
        display: block; 
        text-align: left;
        padding:8px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: #808080; color: white;
    }
    #tabulu thead th:first-child
    {
        display:block;
    }

    #tabulu td:first-child
    {
        display:block;
    }
 
</style>
```

```html
<div id="tabulu"> <table><thead><tr><th>Feature Name</th><th>Feature ID </th><th>Platform</th><th>Version Number</th><th>Checklist 1.1</th><th>Checklist 1.2</th><th>Checklist 1.3</th><th>Additional Information</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>AutoTest</td><td>REL0012</td><td>Web Application</td><td>1.2</td><td>Name: AutoTest Points
SubFeature Unique ID: Auto001
Possible Risk ID: RISK_Auto_001
Test Case Description: This test is for testing the flow
Steps to proceed: Step1- Open RF
Step2- Run RF
Step3- Exit RF
Pre-Requisite: RF Needed
Post-Requisite: Successful execution of the test
Inputs: bla bla bla
Expected Output: output-bla  bla
Test: High
Comment: No Comment</td><td>Name: 
SubFeature Unique ID: 
Possible Risk ID: 
Test Case Description: 
Steps to proceed: 
Pre-Requisite: 
Post-Requisite: 
Inputs: 
Expected Output: 
Test: 
Comment:</td><td>Name: 
SubFeature Unique ID: 
Possible Risk ID: 
Test Case Description: 
Steps to proceed: 
Pre-Requisite: 
Post-Requisite: 
Inputs: 
Expected Output: 
Test: 
Comment:</td><td>Additional Description Additional Description</td></tr></tbody></table> </div>
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the problem. There is a table with just one thead and one tbody - as it should be. And the th cells are at the top of the columns of their respective tds cells, as they should be.  What is it that needs to change?

Comment: Hi @AHaworth, thanks for the reply. If you run the Code Snippet and scroll down, you can see the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't run the snippet. I suspect you'll have to use Javascript to do a proper transposition. Does the 2021 answer from @johnvkumpf here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297591/how-to-invert-transpose-the-rows-and-columns-of-an-html-table/66308509#66308509 help?

Comment: Possible to change the html elements from `<table>`, `<thead>` etc to `<div>`s? If so, you could use flexbox https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060437/9731999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:grid` is your friend.

To make the `th`s and `td`s the grid items, set the tbody, thead and tr elements to `display:contents`.

Allocate two columns with `grid-template-columns:auto auto;`

and set the auto flow order to columns first with `grid-auto-flow:column;`, and specify that the  the `th` elements get filled in the first column, and the `td` elements into the second column with `grid-column:`.

```css
#tabulu table {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
}
#tabulu thead, #tabulu tbody, #tabulu tr {
  display:contents;
}
#tabulu td {
  grid-column:2;
  padding:8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*multiline wrap*/
  white-space:pre-wrap; 
}
#tabulu th {
  grid-column:1;
  text-align: left;
  padding:8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #808080; color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabulu"> <table><thead><tr><th>Feature Name</th><th>Feature ID </th><th>Platform</th><th>Version Number</th><th>Checklist 1.1</th><th>Checklist 1.2</th><th>Checklist 1.3</th><th>Additional Information</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>AutoTest</td><td>REL0012</td><td>Web Application</td><td>1.2</td><td>Name: AutoTest Points
SubFeature Unique ID: Auto001
Possible Risk ID: RISK_Auto_001
Test Case Description: This test is for testing the flow
Steps to proceed: Step1- Open RF
Step2- Run RF
Step3- Exit RF
Pre-Requisite: RF Needed
Post-Requisite: Successful execution of the test
Inputs: bla bla bla
Expected Output: output-bla  bla
Test: High
Comment: No Comment</td><td>Name: 
SubFeature Unique ID: 
Possible Risk ID: 
Test Case Description: 
Steps to proceed: 
Pre-Requisite: 
Post-Requisite: 
Inputs: 
Expected Output: 
Test: 
Comment:</td><td>Name: 
SubFeature Unique ID: 
Possible Risk ID: 
Test Case Description: 
Steps to proceed: 
Pre-Requisite: 
Post-Requisite: 
Inputs: 
Expected Output: 
Test: 
Comment:</td><td>Additional Description Additional Description</td></tr></tbody></table> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for.
Really appreciate your help